# same basic HTML page looks differently in Firefox, if launched from server or desctop

Tags: php, html, css, firefox

I spent quite much time on this one, and finally I figured, that if I launch the same very basic page from desktop and php-server (WAMP or Denwer, tried both), the DIV has different size. It happens only in Firefox (42.0). What the heck?

HTML page source:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:365px; height:80px; background: #0099ff;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking in detail at the Rules section of the Firefox Developer Tools. It will tell you exactly what CSS rules it is using to cause the box to be the size that it is, including differing or custom user stylesheets. Also be sure to check the box model tab to see what components of the box model are causing it to be the size that it is.

Also check that you haven't zoomed in on that tab. It is unlikely, but possible.

Add a screenshot of each of both of these areas to your question for clarification.

Comment: omg. it was zoomed. I restarted not only browser, but also my PC, and it kept being zoomed. thanks :D